# Gnome shell extensions shows as warning icon

Tags: gnome-shell-extension

Some of my shell extensions render as a warning icon:
[image]

When I click on them, the panel shows the correct data, so it's running to some extent.

This is Ubuntu 23.04, but has the same problem on earlier version.

This extension happens to be Freon, but I have the same problem with others.
https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/841/freon/

I've tried alt-f2 + r and logging out and in with no difference.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will not help you solve your issues, but in my experience with 23.04 and shell extensions (which I rely on extensively) is that Gnome 44 (ALL Distro's) is not very "extension friendly" , and for this reason I am sticking with 22.04 LTS. I don't like all the extreme "roundness" in Gnome 44 anyway.

I tried the Freon extension on Ubuntu 22.04.02 and it runs fine...

If you want to try psensor in the meantime, I highly recommend. Can customize names and set alarms.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 23.10 and Freon extension has been running without issues for several months until last week. I assume some update has broken the extension and now it is not working anymore.